# Migrating von APC to APCU in php application

Tags: php, modx, apc, modx-revolution, apcu

the content management framework MODX provides the option to use APC as caching engine. I figured out that I might be able to migrate that to APCu.

I copied and edited all code so that i have a second option now that offers APCu as cache engine. As my php skills have descreased in the last years, I am struggling with the correct way to rewrite the constructor.

The original code is like this:

```
class xPDOAPCCache extends xPDOCache {
public function __construct(& $xpdo, $options = array()) {
    parent :: __construct($xpdo, $options);
    if (function_exists('apc_exists')) {
        $this->initialized = true;
    } else {
        $this->xpdo->log(xPDO::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "xPDOAPCCache[{$this->key}]: Error creating APC cache provider; xPDOAPCCache requires the APC extension for PHP, version 2.0.0 or later.");
    }
}
[...]
```

I rewrote that like this:

```
class xPDOAPCuCache extends xPDOCache {
   public function __construct(& $xpdo, $options = array()) {
        parent :: __construct($xpdo, $options);
        if (function_exists('apcu_exists')) {
            $this->initialized = true;
        } else {
            $this->xpdo->log(xPDO::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "xPDOAPCuCache[{$this->key}]: Error creating APCu cache provider; xPDOAPCuCache requires the APCu extension for PHP.");
        }
    }
    [...]
```

That can't work, as APCu does not take the same parameters as APC did.
(See http://php.net/manual/de/apciterator.construct.php and http://php.net/manual/de/apcuiterator.construct.php)

How to I need to edit this contructor to have my CMF work with APCu as cache engine?

Answer (score 1):

Your code example doesn't seem to refer to APCIterator at all? So it's hard to say what changes would it take.

I suggest you take a look at [apcu_bc](https://pecl.php.net/package/apcu_bc), which provides layer of compatibility with APC API on top of APCu. I am not sure about iterator specifically, but I had successfully used this package for quite a while, until I gradually migrated onto native APCu API.